# mySQL: How to add a new line and trim empty spaces

Tags: mysql

I need to clean a text column on a table in a mySQL database.

The text looks very similar to the following:

```
<p>This is the content of a song,<br>
lyrics go here<br>
lyrics of the song<br>
end of first paragraph.</p>
<p>

Testing data,<br>
this is more text</p>
<p>

Testing more data,<br>
this is another text</p>
```

I need the following:

```
<p>This is the content of a song,<br>
lyrics go here<br>
lyrics of the song<br>
end of first paragraph.</p>

<p>Testing data,<br>
this is more text</p>

<p>Testing more data,<br>
this is another text</p>
```

In other words, i need to add a new line after `</p>` and trim spaces between `<p>` and the text

I have an idea on how to add a new line after `</p>`

```
UPDATE lyrics SET lyrics = REPLACE(lyrics, '</p>', '</p>\n\n')
```

But i have no idea on how to remove the empty text between `<p>` and the text itself.

```
BEFORE:

<p>

Testing data,<br>
this is more text</p>


AFTER:

<p>Testing data,<br>
this is more text</p>
```

Comment: Any scripting language, and I do mean any, would be better than trying to do this in MySQL with its extremely primitive function set.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replacing `'<p>\n\n'` with `'<p>'`?

Edit:

I'm agreeing with tadman's comment, but if you desperately need to do this in SQL i think your best bet is to try more *combinations*...

Btw after checking your pasted data you should really have tried replacing `<p> \n\n` **(with a space)**

If that doesn't work, maybe `\r` line feeds are screwing something up? (I don't even know if that would matter)

Either way, this is not a very stabile solution. I would at least *consider* some alternative approach/language.

Comment: Edited my answer. Did you also try with a space after the <p> tag?

Comment: I finally decide it to go with a PHP script... Thanks again for everybody's advice.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried this:

```
UPDATE lyrics SET lyrics = REPLACE(lyrics, '<p>\n\n', '<p>')
```

Comment: Then you have blank spaces somewhere after `<p>` or the encoding character for new row is not `\n`